# Open new Screen in Android?

Tags: android

Hi I am new to android. 
In my application if user selects the button in the alertDialog I need to open a new screen and I have to display some message on that screen. How to open a new screen?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You open a new activity (i.e screen) by creating and firing off a new intent:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, YourNewActivity.class)
startActivity(intent)
```

Answer (score 4):

comment to Erich Douglass post:
and don't forget to describe it into AndroidManifest.xml like

```
<activity android:name=".YourNewActivity" android:label="@string/app_name" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't adding this line inside the buttonhandler method of the alert dialog work?

```
setContentView(R.layout.screenx);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this,

```
Button btt1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

btt1.setOnClickListener( View.OnClickListener() {


        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            //Starting a  Intent
            Intent next=  Intent(getApplicationContext(), second.class);

            startActivity(next);
        }       

    });
```

You should create btt1.setOnClickListener( View.OnClickListener() {

```
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            //Starting a  Intent
            Intent next=  Intent(getApplicationContext(), pack_detail.class);

            startActivity(next);
        }       

    });
```

second java file look like,

```
public class second extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.secondx);


    }
}
```

and you should create secondx.xml file,
and don't forget to add below statement into manifest

```
<activity :name=".second">  </activity>
```

good luck ...